# Can we have an on-the-fly LaTeX parser?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [We need Tex markup…](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/we-need-tex-markup)

Can we have the option of rendering particular snippets of (La)TeX code? I think it would greatly help beginners with associating commands with the expected output. For example (forgive my example, I'm a beginner):

> ```
> code here
> code here
> code here
> ```
>
> The last line causes the paragraph to indent too much to the right, which looks ugly.

Having an on-the-fly LaTeX parser would allow us to see what the asker or answerer sees firsthand. The author can choose which part of the code to parse.

I imagine a two-column layout where the left side displays the code in `this style`, and the right side displays the output. Repeatedly seeing a command with the expected output can help in drilling down the basics.

Comment: This is a duplicate, see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7/we-need-tex-markup

Comment: It is also similar to the question [Link to online LaTeX compiler](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3164/link-to-online-latex-compiler)

Answer (score 1):

Very much in favour of this. Other Stack Exchange sites already have this. I think it was already enabled here once, but was disabled due to problems. I don’t recall what these problems were, though.