# Why tex.stackexchange cannot have a snippet to run (La)TeX?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I know that a lot of users asked for a way to insert support for LaTeX code (or at least equations) like math.stackexchange and other SE sites. All of them received as comment/answer that this site is about (La)TeX, so all of the user need to see the actual code and not a result that can change based on different factors. In fact, I'm not asking to a way to insert (La)TeX code like other sites, I'm asking why we could not have a snippet, like the one on stackoverflow for HTML, JS and CSS, that has TeX Live on it.

Of course there will be cases when this is not enough, in these cases one could simply use the classical way of asking questions, i.e. post the TeX code and the resulting pdf.

Note that I'm not sure that this wasn't asked before, but I googled it and the only question that I found were about the possibility to insert (La)TeX code like math.stackexchange, not with a snippet.

Comment: because TeX is not browser engine compatible. There has to be an additional compilation engine that runs the snippet. Then you are with different versions different distros etc. and also some service that would do this for free for a super niche and obscure technology.

Comment: You mean that the same source file, compiled with the same version of the compiler with the same options  could produce different results if the system is windows, ubuntu, fedora, mac OS, etc. or if the version of the OS is different?

Comment: Similar? https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6111/117534

Comment: @Troy Yep, is pretty much a duplicate of that question. Still I would like to have that feature but I understand why most don't want it. So I think that probably it will never be implemented.

Comment: I cannot close for duplication even if the question is mine. So I only flagged it as duplicate. If someone want to flag it as duplicate is appreciate. (I don't want to simply close it without marking it a duplicate)

Comment: @giusva And yes, different OS can have a different result. Take for example a case sensitive system vs. one without. In the case sensitive system (for example osx) `\usepackage{Lipsum}` will produce an error, while it will compile without problem on windows.