# Is there a built-in compiler that processes my TeX code and includes pictures of the output in my question/answer?

Tags: discussion

Does the TeX Stack Exchange have an online compiler where I can view the output of my code and include it in my question/answer instead forcing people to screenshot them manually? If it doesn't exist, is there a plan to integrate one in the future?

Comment: using an image allows you to focus in on the problem part of the output. Also it avoids worrying [if a site such as texlive.net](https://texlive.net/run?%5Cdocumentclass%7Barticle%7D%0A%5Cusepackage%7Bamsmath%7D%0A%5Cbegin%7Bdocument%7D%0A%24x%5E%7B%5Ctext%7Bhello%20world%7D%7D%24%0A%5Cend%7Bdocument%7D) is still active for people reading in 10 years time, and if it will show the same problem with an updated system

Comment: Related question: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6111/why-cant-tex-se-compile-my-tex-code