# Updating old questions and answers

Tags: discussion, editing

There are some questions and answers that need updating. For example, [We need TeX markup ...](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/we-need-tex-markup) has a link to Google Charts which leads to an Error 404 page.  Would an add comment automatically inform the author of the question?  What if the author is no longer a regular visitor?  Is there another method of updating? Finally, this may not be the only question that needs updating.  I will ask the question, however, I do not see an answer other than everyone being vigilant about it.  How would you update ALL questions that need updating?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Community editing is part of the way the StackExchange network. Lower reputation users can suggest edits, while people with lots of reputation (over 3k I think) can simply edit directly. So you should feel free to suggest improvements.

The only thing I would ask is that no one overdoes it. Ideally, the front page is mainly made up of new questions. So editing half a dozen old questions a day is probably okay, but doing thirty is not!

Comment: I would rather say that the front page ideally is made up of a good mix of questions.

Comment: It's 2k for editing rights.